# my root page showing blank when i use "use client " nextjs 13.3

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

Why does my Next.js 13.3 app root page display blank when I use 'useClient' on it, even after reinstalling Next.js and clearing cache?"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my component to an arrow function worked for me. Example:

```js
Function Home (){
//...
return ...
}
```

To

```js
Const Home = () => {
//...
return ...
}
```